# Using Javascript to insert css link into the head of a page

Tags: javascript

I 3rd party site that includes this script:

```
 var foo = "Hello World!";

      (function() {
        var foo = "Goodbye World!";
        document.write("<p class='something'>Inside our anomymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
       })();
```

I would now like to insert (using pure javascript) an external reference to a style sheet. How can this be done?

Using jquery you could do it like this:

```
var css_link = $("<link>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet", 
    type: "text/css", 
    href: "style.css" 
});
css_link.appendTo('head');
```

however I need to keep this pure javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly tried below in Chrome and it works..

```
var styleEl = document.createElement("link");
styleEl.type = "text/css";
styleEl.href = "style.css";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `<script>` tag in the head like this:

```
<head>
    <script>
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');
    </script>
</head>
```

The `document.write()` function appends whatever text you have as the parameter right where the script is.

Comment: I think OP means at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at runtime like this:

```
var css = document.createElement("LINK");
css.href = "style.css";
css.type = "text/css";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

*Edit: document.head is compatible with normal browsers and IE9+*